# How to test apps which are developed using XAMARIN

Tags: xamarin, multi-device-hybrid-apps, xamarin-test-cloud

How testing will be carried out on apps which are developed using Xamarin ? As i am totally new on it please help me out .Is xamarin test cloud is only used for UI testing ? Manual testing is possible or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin applications are as native as a native Application, you can test them like you test native android and iOS application.

Xamarin Test cloud let you do automatic UI testing or normal Unit testing.

Xamarin Test cloud don't do Manual testing, in that case you must do it by yourself.

Note: The UI tests and Unit tests must be written before upload the application to the Test Cloud. Test cloud will only execute them in a range of devices selected by you.

Comment: Unit Testing is usually done by developers right ?? So we can test the application manually and for automation we can use test cloud or even Appium right ??

Comment: Yes but i guess you are somehow confusing it. Please read my edited answer hope it clarify it for you.